# dart server: retrieve data from Request

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-server

I was trying to create a simple dart server, glad it's working, but...

```
   Future<Response> _echoHandler(Request request) async{
    final message = await request.readAsString();
    print(message);
    return Response.ok('$message\n');
  }
```

this is how that message looks like

```
----------------------------116375419757550841191749
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

asdf
----------------------------116375419757550841191749--
```

Postman testing[image]

I want to extract this message.

Comment: Couldn't encode parameters in json from Postman, So I tried running client also in dart using http package, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode your data in the Json format then you can retrieve your data from the response

Comment: I'm sending data from postman as FarmData. I believe that will be send as JSON. But the data I'm getting inside the server is not in JSON format.

Comment: ask your backend developer to send the data in JSON format and then you can decode it using JSON encoder

Answer (score 0):

For me.
I change `form-data` to `raw`.
Then I can get data by using:

```
String jsonString = await request.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).join();
var data = json.decode(jsonString);
```

However, I want to use `form-data` too.
I am converting another language server API to dart language. So, this must test in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

After I read [this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver). I found [`shelf_multipart`](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_multipart) package can get data and files from the request with `form-data`.

You can follow my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255231/17798537).